# cp: cannot create directory 'ABC.DEF/G/H': Structure needs cleaning

Tags: ext4, cp

What does it mean "Structure needs cleaning" ?
I've never seen such error code before - and `man cp` is not that helpful.

It has happened to me on `ext4`.

I was trying to copy directory using:

```
cp -arv dirname dirname.bak
```

Comment: What commands are you trying to run?

Comment: @tchen Thanks for suggestion! Improved question with that crucial detail

Comment: @Wildcard - hands made me surprise. Of course `man cp` - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some googling told me that there was a patch to ext4 last year that mentions returning EUCLEAN upon an out of space error.
E.g. https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/452275/

> The fix is either to run e2fsck -E bmap2extent, or to chattr +e the file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it turned out that problem was one level below.

To be more specific, I had an `partition.img` image file, on external usb ntfs harddrive. The problem happened to ntfs partition, which started to report 0 free bytes, despite it should have 800GiB... therefore, writes stopped to be possible on underlying drive, so loop-mounted ext4 drive couldn't operate and started to report errors as described above.

Let me mart Ralph's answer as solution, as this gave me a hint in driving further investigation.